# Serialised communication between languages

Tags: java, objective-c, networking

My universities peer to peer communication course uses an in house client/server program for demonstration and (i think) extending it is part of the assessment. The program we use is written in java and uses serialisation for the network communication.

To get a better grip I want to try reimplementing the protocol used in objective c, but googling around I cant find any information on using serialised data between languages. I would like to keep this as simple as possible, ideally be able to drop my replacement server/client onto a network and have it behave.

**Edit** Didnt actually ask a question there.

Is it possible to communicate between the two serialised formats, How can I make this work without reverse engineering the format java uses.

Comment: That sounds delightful. Did you happen to have a question too?!

Comment: This is going to be an exercise in pain.

Comment: I thought as much; a couple of quick searches didnt bring up anything .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java serialization protocol (if it's built-in default Java serialization) is documented, so you won't have to reverse engineer it - check [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/2915) and [this link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html). However, if you can, use JSON, XML or XML-RPC; it will be much simpler than creating Java serializer/deserializer in another language.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend avoiding writing (de)serialization support of java's native serialization in another language.

If you can change the existing Java server and clients, use a more language agnostic serialization format.

Assuming that you are not allowed to make that sort of change, I would define the new protocol, and implement a bridge in Java. The bridge (process) would establish a connection on behalf of each client that connects to it, and translate messages between the Java serialized and language agnostic form. This will provide a good migration strategy.